# Why I'm not able to print the error messages in AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, response

I've following HTML code:

```
<a href="#" id="promotion_status_1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default brmodalbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#BrandImageModal" id="1">On</button>
</a>

<div class="container">
  <div class="modal fade" id="BrandImgeModaal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="brand_id" id="brand_id" value="{$data.id}">
          <input type="text" name="admin_url" id="admin_url" value="http://localhost/abc.com">    
          <input type="text" name="op" value="upload_brand_image">    
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Brand Image</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="messages"></div>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery AJAX Code :

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  var formdata = false;
  if(window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
  }    
  var formAction = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'manufacturers.php',
    cache       : false,
    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
    //data      : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize() + '&' + $.param({'op':'upload_brand_image'}),
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,

    success: function(response) { alert(response); return;
      if(response.error == 1) {             
        $('#BrandImageModal').modal('hide');
      } else { 
        $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response);
      }
    },
    dataType:"JSON"
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

PHP Code:

```
$request = $_REQUEST ;
switch( $op ) {
    case "upload_brand_image":

      $ret = $objManufacturer->UploadBrandImage($request, $_FILES, $allowed_image_extension, $manuf_error_messages);

      if(!$ret) { 
        $error_msg = $objManufacturer->GetAllErrors();

        $response = array(
          "error" => 1,
          "error_message" => $error_msg
        );

        echo(json_encode($response));
      } else {        
        if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
          upload_file_now( $_FILES['file'], $brand_image_path, $t, $brand_name, $ext);          
        }      
      }
      die;
      break;
  }
```

The `$error_msg` array contains following content :

```
Array
(
    [domain_id] => Please select domain
    [brand_name] => Brand name can't be blank
    [brand_name_invalid] => Brand name is not valid, it should be alphabetic
    [email] => Brand email can't be blank
    [email_invalid] => Brand email is not valid
    [brand_image] => Brand image can't be blank
    [brand_image_format] => Please upload brand image in a proper format
    [brand_image_size] => Brand image size is greater than 5 MB
    [brand_image_dimesnions] => Only upload brand image having dimensions >= 940 X 370 px
    [details] => Brand details can't be blank
)
```

I'm not able to print the messages contained in this array in bootstrap modal.

Where I'm doing wrong? Would someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks

Comment: you have `alert(response); return;` the return will force the termination of the rest of the function... remove the `return` from there

Comment: @ArunPJohny:I added return to for debugging purpose. Even after removing return it's not printing error messages.

Comment: whether it is alerting the proper value?

Comment: Look at this line `$('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response);`  To write the error message you should make it into `$('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response.error_message);`  since your returning a json object. And you are putting it into a text.  `reponse` is still the object and not the error message inside the object.

Comment: also that should be in the `if` block not in the `else` block

Comment: @ArunPJohny,@andrex:Can I access the value from $_POST array in AJAX response? Suppose I want to access $_POST['id'] in ajax success. Can I ?If yes how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use error messages from PHP file into AJAX response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274254/how-to-use-error-messages-from-php-file-into-ajax-response)

Answer (score 0):

> just change the success code...

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
var form = $(this);
var formdata = false;
if(window.FormData) {
formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
}

var formAction = form.attr('action');
$.ajax({
type        : 'POST',
url         : 'manufacturers.php',
cache       : false,
data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
//data      : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize() + '&' + $.param({'op':'upload_brand_image'}),
contentType : false,
processData : false,

success: function (response) {
          alert('successful : ' + response);
      },
      error: function(data, errorThrown)
      {
          alert('request failed :'+errorThrown);
      } 
dataType:"JSON"
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, json data is passed from server to broswer as text, in order to use it sensibly you need to convert it to a proper JSON object using `$.parseJSON()`

So try

```
success: function(response) { 
  response = $.parseJSON(response);
  if(response.error == 1) {
```

Also modern browsers all have a javascript debugger associated with them. Get used to using it. Then you can set a breakpoint on the first line of the `success:` method and view the contents of the returned data, and pretty much everything else thats in scope as well.